# $near requires geojson point, given geojson point

Tags: mongodb

I have documents which contain a geo field like the below.

```
"geo" : {
    "type" : "Point",
    "coordinates" : [
        37.44609999,
        -121.88355687
    ]
},
```

I have created a spatial index, proof below.

```
db.collection.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
        "_id" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "db.collection",
        "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
        "geo.coordinates" : "2dsphere"
        },
        "ns" : "db.collection",
        "name" : "geo.coordinates_2dsphere"
    }
]
```

However when I execute the following query (verbatim from the MongoDB manual ).

```
db.collection.find( { 'geo.coordinates': { $near: 
                                            { $geometry :
                                                { type : "Point", 
                                                  coordinates: [ 37.44609999, -121.88355687 ] } }, 
                                                  $maxDistance: 1000
                                         } } )
```

I get the following error.

```
error: {
    "$err" : "$near requires geojson point, given { type: \"Point\", coordinates: [ 37.44609999, -121.88355687 ] }",
    "code" : 16681
}
```

Can someone enlighten me as to why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flip the points as such:

"geo" : {
    "type" : "Point",
    "coordinates" : [
        -121.88355687,
        37.44609999
    ]
},

Otherwise, check your coordinates to see if they are real:
http://geojsonlint.com/

Comment: According to geojsonlint.com my coordinates are specified in the wrong order. But my documents are Tweets taken directly from the Twitter Streaming API. Does this mean that Twitter are creating invalid geoJSON for every single tweet in their stream? Also the only solution to this issue seems to be for me to flip the coordinates in every document (tweet) that I have collected so far.

Comment: Nevermind, it appears Twitter realized the error. All tweets now have a coordinates field where the coordinates are specified in the correct order and a geo.coordinates field where they are backwards.